# Проблемы с возвратом значения функции ПОИСКПОЗ в ячейку excel

Tags: excel

Мне необходимо перевести таблицу из вертикального формата (вся информация о наблюдении находится в одной строке(например, национальность - год рождения - средний вес) в горизонтальный (напр. ось Х - национальность, У - год рождения, в таблице - средний вес). "Шапка" по обеим осям у меня заполнена. Нашел на англоязычном форуме подробное решение этого вопроса, вот ссылка 
http://www.exceltactics.com/vlookup-multiple-criteria-using-index-match/
Index = Индекс, Match = Поискпоз в русской версии. Однако функция "поискпоз" выдаём мне #Н/Д. Что самое интересное, если открыть подробную информацию о функции, значение отображается, но в ячейке упорно остаётся #Н/Д. Скриншоты прилагаются. В них отдельно выписана функция ПОИСКПОЗ, так как ошибка именно в ней
[image: Наличие значения]
[image: #H/Д в ячейке]

Comment: а где скриншоты?

Comment: Поменял фотохостинг, теперь должно отображаться. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вводите формулу, использующую массивы, поэтому для ввода формулы используйте не клавишу `ENTER` а сочетание клавиш `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!
Так долго над этим мучался, а всё оказалось так тривиально. Без Вас бы ни за что в жизни об этом не вспомнил

Answer (score 0):

Можно без применения формул массива, с использованием доп. столбца в таблице исходных данных (или на другом листе со ссылками на таблицу исходных данных).
На больших диапазонах этим можно уменьшить количество вычислений.

В доп. столбце сцепляем два значения:

```
=A2&H2
```

если на другом листе:

```
=data!A2&data!H2
```

Формула для поиска:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСКПОЗ(A4&B4;доп_столбец;));ПОИСКПОЗ(A4&B4;доп_столбец;);)

=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ПОИСКПОЗ(A4&B4;доп_столбец;);"")
```

Прошу обратить внимание: в первой формуле при ошибке (значение не найдено) результатом будет 0 (ноль), во второй - "" (пустая текстовая строка).Текст может мешать, если результаты поиска будут использованы для дальнейших вычислений. Лучше в числовые диапазоны текст не вставлять. Ноль можно скрыть в параметрах листа:

меню *Файл-Параметры-Дополнительно-Показать_параметры_для_листа*, убрать галку "*Показывать нули.*.."